# Sidebar list is getting pushed to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has a dark grey sidebar that has a ul in it that is holding some navigation. Currently the UL is getting pushed over within the side bar.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWZJd/

I would like the UL to be pressed up against the left side of the sidebar. Then I can add some padding to move it over as I see fit.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <header id="myNav" class="top_block navbar-fixed-top" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4Tell</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Console 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Console 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
    </ul>
    </header>
    <aside class="background sidebar">
    <div class="sidenav">
    <ul class="menu side-menu">
        <li><a href="#">NCR at your service</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>My Support Link</li>
                <li>My Asset List</li>
                <li>My Invoices</li>
                <li>My Somthing Else</li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Q2C MAC</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Move</li>
                <li>Add</li>
                <li>Change</li>
                <li>Swap</li>
            </ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="left_block sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_block footer">
        <p class="text-center">Designed by Steve Wilson <br>With contributions from Alex Cronon and Robert Moua</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_block {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}

.bottom_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0; 
}

.left_block {
    display: block;
    float: left; 
}

.right_block {
    display: block;
    float: right; 
}

.center_block {
    display: block;
    width: auto; 
}

.background.sidebar {
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #33404c;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px; 
    border-right: 1px solid;

}

.sidebar {
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 75px;


}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e3e6ea;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.sidenav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #f9fafb;


}

.side-menu {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 2em;

}
```

*Note: I have cut some of the code for Stack Overflow, see the fiddle for a more complete version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust the `padding` and `margin` on your side-menu to 0.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/PWZJd/2/

Comment: Thanks I have been scratching my head for a while. I kept trying to change the padding on the UL itself and the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The default padding on the `ul` element is what's moving it to the right. Just update the padding and you can dock the `ul` up against the left side of the side-bar as close as you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PWZJd/3/